# Base64 в терминале SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, base64

В документации ничего не говорится о наличии какого бы то ни было встроенного метода base64, в смысле для кодирования и декодирования строк по указанному методу. Но возможно есть какое-нибудь расширение, восполняющее данный недостаток? Или можно как-то, используя лишь SQL, конвертировать строки в base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается расширений, о них неведомо: есть ли, нет ли, - при желании можно взять написать все самостоятельно. Если браться за SQL, основной проблемой при конвертировании строки в base64, является отсутсвие возможности дополнять строку символом '\0'. Однако, если сперва конвертировать строку в бинарное представление, дополнив ее окончание тетрадой нулей, дело вполне сдвигается с мертвой точки. Например.

```
WITH bits(i, s) AS (
        VALUES(1, '') UNION ALL SELECT i + 1, (
           WITH bin(p, b) AS ( -- переводим строку в двоичное представление
              VALUES(7, '') UNION ALL -- user:pass - строка, которую будем переводить
                 SELECT p - 1, (UNICODE(SUBSTR('user:pass', i, 1)) >> p) & 1
              FROM bin LIMIT 9 -- берем октетами, первая ячейка пуста, значит всего ячеек 9
           ) SELECT group_concat(b, '') FROM bin
        ) AS c FROM bits WHERE c <> ''
     ),
     chars(c, b, s) AS ( -- символ карты, карта base64 и бинарная строка, дополненная нулями
        VALUES('', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/',
           (SELECT group_concat(s, '') || '0000' FROM bits)
        ) UNION ALL SELECT SUBSTR(b, ( -- извлекаем символы из карты
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 1, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN 32 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 2, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN 16 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 3, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN  8 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 4, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN  4 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 5, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN  2 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(s, 1, 6), 6, 1) & 1 WHEN 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) + 1), 1
        ), b, SUBSTR(s, 7) FROM chars WHERE s <> ''
     )
SELECT RTRIM(group_concat(c, ''), 'A') || (SELECT CASE -- добиваем base64, если есть \0
   LENGTH(group_concat(s, '')) / 8 % 3 + 1 WHEN 3 THEN '=' WHEN 2 THEN '==' ELSE ''
END FROM bits) FROM chars;
```

В результате получите строку *dXNlcjpwYXNz*.
Относительно обратного преобразования дело обстоит гораздо проще: заменяем знаки '=', если таковые имеются в base64 представлении строки, на символ 'A', бьем строку на тетрады и путем нехитрых математических вычислений приводим к привычному для восприятия виду. В переводе это будет примерно так.

```
WITH string(s) AS (SELECT REPLACE('dXNlcjpwYXNz', '=', 'A')), -- в данном случае замена излишняя
     b64map(i, n, s) AS (
        VALUES(1, '', (SELECT s FROM string)) UNION ALL
        SELECT i + 1, printf('%2d', UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) + CASE
                         WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND  90 THEN -65
                         WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) BETWEEN 97 AND 122 THEN -71
                         WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) BETWEEN 48 AND  57 THEN   4
                         WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) = 43 THEN 19
                         WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)) = 47 THEN 16
                      END), s FROM b64map LIMIT (SELECT LENGTH(s) + 1 FROM string)
     ),
     blocks(i, n, s) AS (
        VALUES(1, '', (SELECT group_concat(n) FROM b64map WHERE i != 1)) UNION ALL
        SELECT i + 12, (SUBSTR(s, i, 2) << 18) + (SUBSTR(s, i + 3, 2) << 12) +
                       (SUBSTR(s, i + 6, 2) << 6) + SUBSTR(s, i + 9, 2), s FROM blocks
        LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) / 4 + 1 FROM b64map)
     ),
     decode(s) AS (
        SELECT group_concat(
           CHAR((n >> 16) & 255) || CHAR((n >> 8) & 255) || CHAR(n & 255), ''
        ) FROM blocks WHERE i != 1
     )
SELECT s FROM decode;
```

Надеюсь эти примеры помогут.